# Why and how fast does lightning propagate?

Tags: visible-light, lightning

While looking at [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBYZpsbu9ds) of lightning in 1000 fps I was somewhat surprised that such a frame rate is enough to capture the propagation of [lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning).

I have no clue about photography or physics, but the naive questions I want to ask are:

1. How "quickly" does lightning propagate, and what are the main
   contributing factors to the propagation speed (e.g density of clouds
   etc)?
2. What exactly is propagating? It can't be light, since it's much too fast, so somehow the "sequence of discharges" that is lightning propagates. Why does it do this?

Comment: @DavidWhite That seems more like an answer than like a comment.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136694/2451

Answer (score 1):

There are two processes going on in a lightning strike. There are stepped leaders, searching for the path of least resistance, and there is the lightning strike when that path is found. See youtube.com/watch?v=XWuZqw3LopE. Each process has its own speed, and the stepped leader process may not proceed at a constant speed. Also see youtube.com/watch?v=RLWIBrweSU8.